# ValueError: readline of closed file in Python

Tags: python, csv

This is my code:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    x = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')

for row in x:
    print (row)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: readline of closed file
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you don't actually start reading lines from the file until you hit the `for` loop.  However, at that point (due to the context manager), the file is already closed.

Comment: `with open(...)` keeps the file open for all following *and indented* lines of code. `csv.reader` just defined how to read the file, the lines are read in `for row in x`.

Answer (score 7):

Your indent is out of order

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    x = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')

    for row in x:
        print (row)
```

Is the correct indent

The line, `with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:` creates a file object, but calls the `__close__` method of the file once its block ends. As in Python, an un-indent closes the block, you have exited the block when you write `for row in x:`. Thus `x` is now closed, and you cannot perform any operations on that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not indented properly. Replaced `rb` by `r`.

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','r') as csvfile:
    x = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')

    for row in x:
        print (row)
```